# Solve math equation from TextBox - VB Net

Tags: vb.net, math, textbox, equation

I need help with the next problem I cant solve.

I have three `TextBox`:

1. `PRECIOTextBox` which has a number
2. `FORMULA_ATextBox` which has a math formula like "+10%*2"
3. `PRECIO_ATextBox` which has to display the result of the equation between the 1st and 2nd `TextBox`.

So far I only have the next code that only works to split the string when the percentage symbol appears. So I can resolve equations like: "+10%-20%+10%".

```
    Dim FormulaA As String = FORMULA_ATextBox.Text
    Dim FormulaASeparado() As String
    Dim Precio1 As Double = PRECIOTextBox.Text
    FormulaASeparado = FormulaA.Split("%")

      For x = 0 To FormulaASeparado.Length - 1
          If FormulaASeparado(x).ToString <> "" Then
              If Val(FormulaASeparado(x)) > 0 Then
                  Precio1 = Precio1 + (Precio1 * Val(FormulaASeparado(x)) / 100)
              Else
                  Precio1 = Precio1 - (Precio1 * Math.Abs(Val(FormulaASeparado(x))) / 100)
              End If
          End If
      Next

    PRECIO_ATextBox.Text = Precio1
```

I have no clue on how to solve a formula on a `TextBox` that has "+", "-", "/", "*" and "%".
If any of you has a clue please share. Thanks!

Comment: You will have to write an expression parser, the kind of code used in a compiler.  Do google "vb.net eval function" for basic hits.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on it